# Reciprocity for Lagrange multipliers

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone know of a textbook with explicit examples
of Lagrange multiplier problems of the following type?

Compare the results of :

(a) optimizing  $f(x,y)$   [max or min]  subject to 
    the constraint  $g(x,y) = constant$.

and

(b)  optimizing   $g(x,y)$  subject to the constraint $f(x,y) = constant$.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If $ (f,g) $ are functions of $x$ and $y$ each, $ f - \lambda g = $ const.or extremum ,

$$ f_x - \lambda g_x = 0 ;  f_y - \lambda g_y = 0 ; $$

$$ \lambda =  \dfrac{f_x}{g_x} = \dfrac{f_y}{g_y}. $$

In variational calculus object and constraint are regarded the same way. They can be interchanged with respect to the max/min assignments. If something is  constrained, ie an extremising constraint implies a given object function and vice-versa *automatically*.

In fact there is no need to consider it in one way *only*, except as an entry point when first encountering a situation.

There are many example  pairs in geometry economics, physics ..including (surface area, volume),(length,area), (cost,time) ..